# Dynamically add middleware in app/Http/Kernel.php

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have created a middleware `App\Http\Modules\Post\Middleware\Post.php` and I want to add it in routeMiddleware of `app/Http/Kernel.php` from a service provider. How can I accomplish this?

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class          
];
```

I googled and tried `prependMiddleware` but this is for global middleware right?